# Different scaling on iPhone/iPad

Tags: php, iphone, css, ipad

I'm trying to finish a site for my friends brother, and everything (almost) works fine.

The site is built with a centered container, aprox 15-20% space from the left side.

The problem is though that when you open it in iPhone or iPad the site is scaled so that the space on the left side is removed, the text starts exactly where the screen starts. I hope I'm explaining this right.

Is there a simple way for me to change this only for mobile devices? Too bad I don't have any experience when it comes to designing for phones..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how you are leaving margin on the html page? may be that is not supported on iPhone device. Which version of HTML you are using? On which iPhone you have tested it(3G,4 or other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using percentages to move the container to the left?

Are you sure you didn't give the container a fixed `width` and `margin:0 auto;` with CSS?
And then put this meta tag into the head of the HTML webpage so that phones treat it right?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

Because as far as I know, you are using the `margin:0 auto;` method of centering.

Give the container some padding, for example `padding:1em;` and you should be fine. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't moved it with percentages, the width is set to 100% through css, with 0 padding and margin, is auto necessary?

Thank you for your help! Will that meta tag help us?

Comment: the meta tag resizes the view so that it takes only the space it needs on the phone (I only tested with androids). If it's width is 100%, then how do you get the spacing on the left?

Comment: Hmm I haven't fixed it yet. A friend is looking at it right now, but it seems it's quite more difficult than I thought.

The url is http://www.seorapport.se (temporary). On desktop it shows normally but on the iphone the space is removed.. We're looking at it.. Have you got any ideas? Thanks bro.

Comment: by the looks of it you just need to add some padding. but you need to do it for each element that touches the sides, for example `.port { padding:0 10px; }` you might want to reduce the width according to the extra padding, looks like a lot of work, so I'll have another peek tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well I don't know if it requires a lot of work, the site works with include menu.php, main.php (index) and footer.php. There about 30 pages under it but they're controlled by the style.css which is global. Maybe I don't need to change that much. But it would be much easiser if there was a meta tag or something that could resize the site when accessed by an iphone :)
Thank you @YuriKolovsky

Comment: you can always use the `<style type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
    /*for iphone only*/
</style>` like Waqas suggested, but you would have to add the padding to each element anyway essentially doing the same thing :) or give the body some fixed width like `body {width:whateverwidthiphonehas;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can include a css in header of the page by looking for its device parameter

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
    /*for iphone only*/
</style>
```

OR another way is to create a css file mobile.css for mobile devices only and include this css by the javascript below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // checking if the device is iphone, ipod or ipad
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") > 0)
        || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPod") > 0)
        || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") > 0)) {
        // including the css file
        document.write("<link href='mobile.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the first code you posted, and I think it will work. I just don't know how to resize the site for iphone so that it adds a little space. Like on apple.com, it gives like 5-10px space which would suit great for me.